# sum all values for table column on html page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a sample table look like this and data refreshed every 5 minute to show latest.example -

```
TollFree                    US                      Canadian                      
7,312                       826                     141,128
```

I need to add and calculate total of above all.

```
 Total Records -
```

This is what i have tried so far-
    http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/2666/

HTML page has 6 tables which has different number of columns to do same calculation. Trying to use same script in all as td class is same.

Comment: Woah, that's a ton of non-breaking spaces.  Dude, you should look into css padding/margins/etc for styling.

Comment: Aside from that, if you put a span element around all the numbers you want to sum with a common class, then it's a simple operation to select all those, parse those into numbers, and then sum them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few errors in your code. Here is the working version : http://jsfiddle.net/2q06sv8w/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var expenses = $('.expenses');
            var expenseTotal = $('#expenses_sum');
            expenseTotal.html('0');
            $.each(expenses, function (index, object) {
                var boldTag = $(object).find('b');
                if (boldTag && boldTag.length > 0 && $(boldTag[0]).html() != '') {
                    expenseTotal.html(parseInt(expenseTotal.html()) + parseInt($(boldTag[0]).html().replace(/,/g, '')));
                }
            })
        });
```

1. The selector '.' is used to select elements matching a class name and '#' is used to select an element matching an id. So 'expenses_sum' must be an id and not a class.
2. You should use html() and not val() to get and set the content of a td tag.
3. The td tag contains the value inside a bold tag so you must use the html() on the bold tag.
4. Declaring global variables and using $ prefix for variables does not look necessary here.

Comment: thanks acnn for such a nice explanation with logic.http://jsfiddle.net/7vd6bx4k/  does not works though.

Comment: I gave you the solution anyway

Comment: @acnn. Hi, i checked your fiddle answer, but comma seperated values are not added

Comment: @ Acnn thanks. total should be - 149677 but your update returns 1378.

Comment: @sana, you are wright, the comma seperated values are not adding

Comment: @sana oops i did not notice the commas. Updated : http://jsfiddle.net/2q06sv8w/3/

Answer (score 5):

Here we go:

```js
var summ = Number($("td:nth-child(1)").text()) + Number($("td:nth-child(2)").text()) + Number($("td:nth-child(3)").text());
console.log("Result: " + summ);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>V</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Edit for your request:**

```js
var summ = 0;
$("td").each(function() {
  summ += Number($(this).text());
});;
console.log("Result: " + summ);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>V</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Marco, thank you .but above will be like a hard coded for a table with 3 column. I want to use same jq script to add total for any number of column.can you suggest please?